# What do the spanning set and the basis look like geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry

Think it would be intuitive to provide some kind geometric interpretation of the spanning set and the basis of a finite dimensional vector space.

I understand that the spanning set is the set of linear combinations of $S$ where $Span(S) = V$ for some vector space $V$.

I also understand that the basis is a linearly independent spanning set.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Choosing a basis is like choosing a system of coordinates. I very strongly stress on the fact that saying *the* basis is a hugh mistake.

Comment: @CaptainLama Named after Edmund Hugh, who often made mistakes.

Comment: In dimension 2, hold up your thumb and forefinger, but make sure they are not parallel; that's what a basis looks like in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In dimension $3$, hold up your thumb, forefinger, and middle finger, but make sure no two are parallel; that's what a basis looks like in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @LeeMosher - Consider $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)$. No two are parallel, but they don't form a basis.

Comment: Yeah, shoulda said "make sure they are not coplanar".

Answer (score 3):

The spanning set would be a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$ dimension vector space. If you consider $n=3$, each plane you see in this picture,
[image]

represents the span of two linearly independent vectors. The blue line is the span of a single vector and the entire space would be the span of three linearly independent vectors. Each black axis is the span of a single basis vector, although you shouldn't think of a particular basis as having precedence over another.

Comment: Thanks, was also wondering what the minimal linear subspace of a vector space would be ?

Comment: Would it be the basis for the subspace ?

Comment: Ive never heard of such a thing but it cant just be the basis as a subspace has infinitely many vectors if its not just {0}